# Can I simulate a specific filesystem while unit testing?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, java-6

I have been googling a little and did not find an answer which suited my specific case.

I am working on a project file manager classes, and discovered that it was developped to behave differently on Windows and Unix filesystems.

More specifically, it is compensating for the case-senstivity in Unix: when a file is not found, the manager will look for it in a case-insensitive way.

Before changing this code, I would like to implement some unit tests. However, our development machines and our CIP are both on Windows, and I have no Unix machine available. The machines and IDEs are provided by the customer. Virtualization is not an option, and dual-booting is even less.

Is there a way to test both Windows and Unix mode while being platform-independant for the build? I think the ideal would be to run the whole Test Class in a mode, and then in the other, but even a more hands-on solution would be great.

In production mode, the file managers are initialized using Spring, but they are the lowest level of the chain, using directly java.io.

Versions: Java 6, JUnit 4.9

Comment: Without knowing the API it is quite hard. Can you mock at one level or another? Can you use, say, JSR 330 to alter the behaviour?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question to answer this as well as I could. We use Spring to initialize those manager, but they are the end of the chain, using directly java.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs) with dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.jimfs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jimfs</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you could create a linux, windows and Mac file systems using

```
 FileSystem fileSystem = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.osX());
 FileSystem fileSystem = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.windows());
 FileSystem fileSystem = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.unix());
```

example

```
class FilePathReader {

    String getSystemPath(Path path) {
        try {
            return path
              .toRealPath()
              .toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
        }
    }
}

class FilePathReaderUnitTest {

    private static String DIRECTORY_NAME = "baeldung";

    private FilePathReader filePathReader = new FilePathReader();

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should get path on windows")
    void givenWindowsSystem_shouldGetPath_thenReturnWindowsPath() throws Exception {
        FileSystem fileSystem = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.windows());
        Path path = getPathToFile(fileSystem);

        String stringPath = filePathReader.getSystemPath(path);

        assertEquals("C:\\work\\" + DIRECTORY_NAME, stringPath);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should get path on unix")
    void givenUnixSystem_shouldGetPath_thenReturnUnixPath() throws Exception {
        FileSystem fileSystem = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.unix());
        Path path = getPathToFile(fileSystem);

        String stringPath = filePathReader.getSystemPath(path);

        assertEquals("/work/" + DIRECTORY_NAME, stringPath);
    }

    private Path getPathToFile(FileSystem fileSystem) throws Exception {
        Path path = fileSystem.getPath(DIRECTORY_NAME);
        Files.createDirectory(path);

        return path;
    }
}
```

All this copied from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jimfs-file-system-mocking).

Comment: I can't test it as I don't have access to the original code, but your answer and the original article seem to describe something that matches precisely my needs at the time, so I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could dualboot Ubuntu easily by installing it with wubi.

I've learnt that unit-test should not access the file system for different reasons (speed being one of them).

For Java 6 look into theese:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaFileManager.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html

If you were to use Java 7 this might help you:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html

Comment: OP says he is using Java 6 though. Java 7 could make this way easier, that's true...

Comment: Machines and software are provided by the customer, and cannot be changed. I cannot install a dual-boot, or even a VM.

Comment: More specific and relevant comment to the rest of your answer. Filesystem access: the managers use directly java.io, and I thought of using JUnit's TemporaryFolder + @Rule to perform those tests. Java 7: The FileSystemProvider was indeed a lead I had seen on another similar topic, and which I was interested into, but I cannot upgrade the Java version. As for your links in case of Java 6, I will have a look as soon as I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a VM to test it on unix. Virtual Box by Oracle is agood virtualization software. Install Ubuntu, or Fedora, or some other unix based OS' Disk Image. Transfer your files to the VM. You can directly check out from your source control into the VM and you should be good to go. Atleast I am assuming that is what you want to do : test your software in both windows and linux, but currently don't have linux at your disposal

Comment: Same remark as above: Machines and software are provided by the customer, and cannot be changed. I cannot install a dual-boot, or even a VM.

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to realistically test this withut a VM or a test server. you will have to convey that to your client. IMO these things can be negotiated with the customer if its a big requirement. Otherwise you can always deliver with the disclaimer. File utilites work quite well when using relative paths. Unlessyou have a "C:\apdir" somewhere in yur code, u shud be good to go

Comment: I thought the final answer might be something like that, but it is always worth asking. Thanks.